# Crear sistema de votaciones

Tags: php, mysql

estoy tratando de crear en mi web un sistema de votaciones, en principio crear el sistema de votaciones no supone ningún problema pero necesitaría que para poder votar, el usuario meta su DNI y si este se encuentra en la base de datos pueda votar, si no que no le deje, también necesitaría que cada usuario guardado en la base de datos únicamente pueda realizar un voto, he pensado en crear una base de datos y que esta se actualice cuando un usuario realice su voto, ya que la votación es una pregunta que se responde con si/no, estaría muy agradecido si pudieran ayudarme con el código, un saludo.

```
CREATE TABLE `votacion` (
  `id` INT(11), 
  `Nombre` VARCHAR(20), 
  `Apellidos` VARCHAR(20), 
  `Licencia` VARCHAR(20), 
  `DNI` VARCHAR(20), 
  `Eleccion` VARCHAR(20), 
  `FNacimiento` VARCHAR(20)
)
```

Comment: Te falta una coma después de cada campo, ¿no? En cualquier caso, ¿en qué pides concretamente ayuda? ¿Con el modelado de los datos? ¿Con el formulario? ¿Con la algorítmica? ¿Los formularios de Google resuelven tu problema? Envíanos algo más y podremos ayudarte a depurarlo... pero como no concretes algo, nos cerrarán la pregunta por estar basada en opiniones...

Comment: Buenas, los formularios de Google no resuelven mi problema ya que necesito que para poder votar de alguna manera se inicie sesión y únicamente puedan votar los que previamente estén en una base de datos, además únicamente puedo permitir un voto por usuario, esto es lo que no sabría como hacer, gracias y un saludo

Comment: Es que, precisamente lo que pides, se puede hacer con formularios de Google: no tienes más que compartir el formulario exclusivamente con los usuarios de una lista y registrar el email de cada respuesta. Después ya decides si quedarte con el primero con el último de los votos que emitan... Con lo que me gusta programar a medida y terminar recomendando a Google, ¿a qué hemos llegado?

Comment: Pero no dispongo de los correos de los usuarios, únicamente de nombre, apellidos, dni y licencia

Comment: Hay mil maneras de hacer esto. Si decides hacerlo con una base de datos adelante, es una buena opción. Te recomendaría que lo combines con Ajax, supongo que tendrías una página donde presentarías la interfaz para votar. Allí pides el DNI, mandas una consulta a la BD y si existe entonces despliegas el contenido que pide el voto, si no lo encuentra pones un mensaje diciendo que no puede votar porque el DNI no se encontró. O, si quieres más seguridad, puedes crear una base de usuarios donde se registran y les asignas una contraseña. Usar sólo el DNI no impide que otros lo usen para votar.

Comment: En cuanto a la tabla, tendría que tener una restricción `UNIQUE` sobre los campos que no se pueden repetir. Supongamos que son varias elecciones y en cada una de ellas cada persona puede votar una sola vez, entonces, esa restricción `UNIQUE` agruparía las columnas `(Eleccion, DNI)`. Y tendrías que verificar antes de la votación si no existe ya un registro para ese DNI y esa Elección antes de permitir votar. Es relativamente fácil montar eso. Ya tienes los enunciados, pero te toca a ti programarlo y si tienes dudas sobre algo en concreto lo preguntas aquí y te ayudaremos.